# Error Adding labels to scatterplot graph in python

Tags: python, label, scatter-plot

Im trying to create a scatterplot chart with labels but I get the next error: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
label = ['Tuvalu', 'Nauru', 'Kiribati', 'Marshall Islands', 'Palau', 'Micronesia']
x = [ 1, 1500, 340, 8902, 5, 250]
y = [ 1, 4, 10, 3, 5, 23]

plt.scatter (x,y)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xscale('log')

for i, label in range(len(label)):
    ax.annotate(label,x[i], y[i])
```

Comment: `ax.annotate(label[i],x[i], y[i]) `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For labels you can use

```
for i in range(len(label)):
   ax.annotate(label[i],(x[i], y[i]))
```

I generally use Plotly as it is an excellent library for visualizations. The error in your code is because of the for loop. If you want you can use Plotly.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
label = ['Tuvalu', 'Nauru', 'Kiribati', 'Marshall Islands', 'Palau', 'Micronesia']
x = [ 1, 1500, 340, 8902, 5, 250]
y = [ 1, 4, 10, 3, 5, 23]
for i in range(0,6):
  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[x[i]],y=[y[i]],mode='markers',name=label[I]))
fig.show()
```

[image: PLOT]

Answer (score 0):

I missed some parenthesis:

```
 ax.annotate(label,(x[i], y[i]))
```